# Ubunt 12.04 LTS Touch pad no longer working after connecting USB mouse

Tags: 12.04, usb, mouse, touchpad, multi-touch

I have a Toshiba Satellite C55 which is configured as a dual boot (Windows 8/ Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

Recently I connected a USB mouse and since the touch pad on the laptop has stopped working with or with out the USB mouse. The two buttons are working. I have referenced a following post but have not been able to find a solution.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Referances**

- [Lenovo T440s deactivate touch pad but keep mouse button function working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380464/lenovo-t440s-deactivate-touch-pad-but-keep-mouse-button-function-working)
- [non functioning of touch pad & mouse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88960/non-functioning-of-touch-pad-mouse)
- [Ubuntu 12.04 - touchpad not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264555/ubuntu-12-04-touchpad-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution** was very simple FN+F5 enable touch pad.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

> sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
>
> synclient TouchpadOff=0
>
> sudo chmod +wrx '/var/lib/dpkg/lock'
>
> sudo apt-get install synaptic

For more details refer to the following link

[12.04 Touchpad not working Asus g51vx-A1](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1967228&page=2&s=62c66755419894eab84d354649d1ea2b)